# The performance of R code degrades after packaging

Tags: r, r-package

I have a piece of R code to process some chromosome data. The original program takes about 5 minutes to finish processing given data. Then I create an R package for my code using RStudio. I tried to build source package and binary package and succeeded. However, after I load built package and run the same function, I found that its performance degrades significantly. It takes more than 30 minutes to finish the data processing.

So I have two questions:

1. Why the packaged code have poorer performance than the original code? Can anyone provide some **general** advice?
2. Is there any options to optimize my code in build process?

Comment: Too vague. There really isn't enough information for us to help. You need to break it down to the actual function, the code, the data,  and the task that seems slowed.